# Hide Copy button in UIActivityViewController

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to hide the default "Copy" button when using the UIActivityViewController? The context of my app has no user for it.

Answer (score 5):

Use the excludeActivityItems property of UIActivityViewController.

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController()

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]
```

Comment: Swift 5: vc.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard]